# Flex 4.5 - Android application keeps running in background, How can I shut it down?

Tags: android, flex4.5

I am building an Android application in Flex 4.5 and I am testing on a Samsung Galaxy S phone.
My application uses GPS and also Google maps.

When I run the application, and I try to close it, the application keeps on running in the background. I would like the application to stop when the user presses the device's home button or when the user clicks the back button until they leave the application.

How can I make the application shut down in both the cases?

Comment: Are you saying that when the user presses the Back button, it is not being destroyed? Do you have threads running?

Comment: Yes, when you click the back button until the home screen, the application still runs in the background.

Answer (score 1):

This is how Android applications are supposed to work.  See here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html

Your application's process is in either the "background" state (if the user pressed how) or "empty" state (if the user pressed back).

Comment: Event when I use the back button, the app remains running in the background. I see it active in the task manager and I can close it from there.

Comment: Yes as described on the link I pointed to, empty processes are kept around for a while so that if the user returns from them they don't need to be re-launched.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you can try using the Activity noHistory flag in the manifest. This will make sure an Activity is finished if navigated away from.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick answers. I tried to add the following line to the -app.xml file in the android.manifestAdditions section. Since I am developing the app in Flex 4.5, I believe this is where it needs to go. "<activity android:noHistory="true"/>". It doesn't make a difference. Am I doing someting wrong or are there other things I can try?